# Самоконтроль на рабочем месте

Tags: поиск-программ

меня интересует программа для блокировки сайтов , программ или вовсе интернета на определённое время . без возможности её отключения . моя проблемма заключаеться в прокрастинации вместо того чтобы работать над проектом , я залипаю в ютубе или играю .

Comment: думаю что выключить нельзя только системные нужные программы как: System Idle Process, System, smss.exe, Memory Compression, Interrupts и т. д. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLib1.png

Comment: @Mell, ну попробуй так антивирус вырубить...

Comment: я вырубил, если ты про новую windows 10

Comment: Это не решение проблемы. Прокрастинация - не болезнь и по этому не лечится. Вам нужно объяснить самому себе, что цель, к которой вы идёте, действительно сделает вас счастливее, чем игры и просмотр ютуба. Думайте о конечной цели и если она далеко, то разбейте путь на важные участки и поймите, что преодоление даже самого короткого участка - это большое достижение в борьбе с самим собой.